# Can I generate SPARQL queries automatically from natural language statement in apache jena API?

Tags: nlp, sparql, jena

I have built a domain specific ontology. And I need a framework over it where user asks a query in natural language and the system turns this query to the SPARQL query automatically. If somehow I extract named entities and query word from the natural language query  statement...  What are the possibilities to have a simple SPARQL query with it. Which tools and techniques might help me?

Note: I only have simple factoid questions right now... not the complicated ones.

I have domain specific ontology. And I need a framework over it where user asks a query in natural language and the system turns this query to the SPARQL query automatically. Can Apache jena API work for it?

Comment: you'll need a Question Answering tool for this - which in fact is research topic.

Comment: "a query in natural language and the system turns this query to the SPARQL" -- Apache Jena does not provide any NLP capability or entity recognition. That would be built on top making calls to the Jena API.